# What age was Avraham's name change?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, avot-patriarch-fathers, abraham, age

As we know Avraham was changed from Avram.
Does anyone know how old Avraham was when he got his name change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the sefer סדר הדורות הקצר, p.9 - It writes that in the year 2047 (counted from the creation of the world) Avraham was aged 99 when he performed milah on himself and his sons on the 13th Nissan. It was at this time his name was changed.

Please find a photo of the page below (please note that the highlighted text is not all relevant to the answer):
[image]

Answer (score 5):

It seems clear from [Bereishit 17:1-5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.17.1) that he was 99 years old.